# koa/supertest - server.close is not a function

Tags: node.js, jestjs, koa2

I've seen previous posts where the issue was that you need to export the instance to be able to call `close()` on the server. I have tried that however I am still getting that error

#### index.ts

```js
import * as Koa from "koa"
import * as logger from "koa-logger"
import * as json from "koa-json"
import * as bodyParser from "koa-bodyparser"
import * as cors from "koa-cors"
import errorHandler from "./middlewares/errorhandler.middleware"
import router from "./routes"

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const app = new Koa()

app
    .use(logger())
    .use(bodyParser())
    .use(errorHandler)
    .use(router.routes())
    .use(router.allowedMethods())
    .use(json())
    .use(cors())


    export const server = app.listen(PORT, (): void => console.log(` Server listening on port ${PORT} - ${ENV} environment`))
```

I have also tried different ways of exporting

```
const appServer = app.listen(...)
export default appServer
```

#### test file

```js
const request = require('supertest');
const server = require('../index');
beforeAll(async () => {
 // do something before anything else runs
 console.log('Jest starting!');
});
// close the server after each test
afterAll(() => {
 server.close();
 console.log('server closed!');
});
describe('basic route tests', () => {
 test('get home route GET /', async () => {
 const response = await request(server).get('/');
 expect(response.status).toEqual(200);
 expect(response.text).toContain('Hello World!');
 });
});
```

also, if I change the `const server = require("../index.ts")` statement into an import then I get the error : `Property 'close' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/Users/path/to/file/")`

So that might be part of the issue as well.

Answer (score 1):

in the test file change the imports

```js
import {server} from "../index"
```